# twitter4jのツイート収集に関する質問です

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

あるキーワードについて一週間分の全てのツイートを取得したいのですが、日付指定をすると指定した期間の近いほうのだいたい7:00~9:00までのツイートしか取得できません
**例**

```
query.setSince("2015-12-06");
query.setUntil("2015-12-08");
```

とすると12月8日の7:00~9:00までのツイートが取得される

コードをどのように書けば一週間分のツイートを取得できますか？
（15分制限等は知っているので何回かにわけて実行するつもりです）

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets
パラメータのcountで指定した分しか取れないので、max_idで順に古いものを辿っていくことなるかと思います。